# Disable reading from site-packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-3.6

```
$ cd python_test_venv/
$ python3.6 -m venv env
$ . env/bin/activate
$ which pip
~/python_test_venv/env/bin/pip
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from [...]/python_test_venv/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
$ pip install javapackages
Requirement already satisfied: javapackages in [...]/python2.7/site-packages
```

Why is is that

1) It reads from site-packages at all? Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), the flag that determines whether or not this should be accessible is False.

2) It reads from site-packages from an older version of Python?

Comment: as a workaround you can try `python3.6 -m pip install javapackages`

Comment: Can you share the `sys.path` that is set when you've activated the venv? `source env/bin/activate && python -c "import os, sys; print(os.linesep.join(sys.path))"`. Also, check whether `PYTHONPATH` is set: `echo $PYTHONPATH`.